# how to extract value inside the tag

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

Script:

```
function checkSensorToday() {
    var okesip; 
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + "api/checkSrTensooday",
        success: function(json) {     
                $('.trafpeople_').text(json.TraficPeople);   
                $('data-percent').text(json.percentageValue);   
        }
    }); 
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="easy-pie-chart percentage" data-percent="42" data-size="46">
    <span class="percent trafpeople_"></span>%
</div>
```

`data-percent` figure would give the percentage of blue color on a cart.

Can I put `json.percentageValue` inside `div` in the `data-percent=""`, to replace 42?

Comment: can u be just little more descriptive

Comment: the div it will give a picture cart,
numbers on the data attribute-percentage will produce a percentage of color on the use of a sensor.

i want to replace data-percent with jquery. 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('[data-percent]').attr('data-percent', json.percentageValue);`

Your selector isn't attribute selector (you need to add []).

In jquery you can get and change attributes using the `attr` like the example above.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following using **jQuery**

```
$('div.easy-pie-chart.percentage').data('%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unwrapped `%` using:

```
 var txt = $(".percentage").contents().filter( function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
 }).text();
```

and for appending above txt to data percent attribute:

```
$('.percentage').data('percent',$('.percentage').data('percent')+txt.trim());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkfc5k2z/)**

**Update:** For replacing data value:

```
$('.percentage').data('percent',json.percentageValue);
```

Comment: where I have to put `json.percentageValue`

Comment: Check the demo above. you can set the new value using `$('.percentage').data('percent',json.percentageValue)`